# How to set/update multiple property in maven during or before maven build

Tags: java, maven

My pom structure looks like - and i am using org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.16.0

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
      <artifactId>manchu-core</artifactId>
      <version>[${myartifact.version}]</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
      <artifactId>manchu-extra</artifactId>
      <version>[${mysecondArtifact.version}]</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now i want to set different versions for the property of both versions during Maven build.
i tried `mvn versions:set-property -Dpropery=myartifact.version -DnewVersion=10.1.1`, but set-propery only set single property and does not set both property values

if I pass it using comma-separated value, it only takes the last property not both

```
mvn versions:set-property -Dpropery=myartifact.version -DnewVersion=10.1.1, -Dpropery=mysecondartifact.version -DnewVersion=10.5.1
```

is there any other option I can use to update/set multiple properties' values?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First why are you using bracket versions? and why using properties for the dependencies.. does that dependency not offer a bom file ... Is that a multi module build?

Comment: yes it is a multi-module build, I am using property because i have to use the same artifacts in different child poms, and during new release, i can change the version directly from Jenkins build instead of changing the pom and creating a new Pull Request every time the version changes

Comment: I would suggest to use dependencyManagement instead of properties ... which means single location in your parent in the dependencyManagement single location where change is needed that's it... Changing the release of the modules which you have inside your multi module build? You should consider using maven-release-pluging or using versions-maven-plugin instead of using properties or alike...

Comment: we are using maven-release-plugin with dependency management, in this case itself we need to change the version of artifacts for release, and to do that we want to update that version during Jenkins build instead of physically changing it and making new commits

Comment: Why do you need to change that yourself.. that's what maven-release-plugin does automatically... ...That sounds like there is something wrong in there ... or the setup/configuration of the plugins or alike are wrong..

Comment: because maven-release update to latest version but we want a specific version while release so instead of changing pom and commit we want to pass it through jenkins job argument and then update it during jenkins build

Comment: `because maven-release update to latest version but we want a specific version while release` ? I don't understand that sentence because you can define the new release version via command line property... ?

Answer (score 1):

The versions:set-property command can only update one property at a time. Something like:

```
mvn versions:set-property -Dproperty=myartifact.version -DnewVersion=10.1.1
mvn versions:set-property -Dproperty=mysecondArtifact.version -DnewVersion=10.5.1
```

You potentially could also want to create a bash script in which you pass 2 parameters and run those two lines above with the values you just passed.

You can also set the properties in the pom like this:

```
<properties>
   <myartifact.version>10.1.1</myartifact.version>
   <mysecondArtifact.version>10.5.1</mysecondArtifact.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Thanks, i don't want to run the same set property command multiple times, because we have lots of properties and it may take time, i opened jira issue on the plugin repo they said there is no such feature for the required use case, so maybe i have to go with different plugin